How is て行ってくれる used here?

せっかく来たんだし！ しばらくのんびりして行ってくれるとうれしいな

The character runs a hostel/hot spring and says this to his friend who came... I understand he's saying he wants the friend to relax, but what nuance does て行って give?

It is just のんびりしていく+くれる

Yeah, is it really 「行って」?  Or did you just type it that way, and it's really in hiragana?

It's really 行って in the manga yes. Though later it's rephrase as ていけ

Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100380/5010

Also related (see the comments below my answer): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/102458/5010
